# How to create Ichimoku "3 lines" signal?

Tags: python, pine-script, algorithmic-trading, indicator

Hi I try to wrote a simple strategy that is based on Ichimoku Cloud.
The strongest and most profitable Ichimoku signal - described by creator of the system Mr.Hosoda - is so called "3 lines signal"
The signal has few conditions:
1. Crossover of conversionLine over baseLine
2. Price close above conversionLine 
3. ConversionLine is above baseLine 
4. BaseLine above Cloud /leadLine1 and leadLine2/ 
5. Displacement line above price

Problem:
When I put all those conditions together I get "no data".

It works but only with fist 3 conditions /crossover and close>conversionline and close>baseline)
When I add conditions 4. and 5. strategy shows "No data". /for example: baseline>leadline1 and baseline>leadline2 and close>displacement/
Works only with condition 1,2,3.
So there is some problem with cloud and displacement, but I cannot find a solution

Please help :)
Thank You

code /only for long entries/:

```
//@version=4
strategy(title="Ichimoku Cloud", shorttitle="Ichimoku", overlay=true)

conversionPeriods = input(9, minval=1, title="Conversion Line Periods"),
basePeriods = input(26, minval=1, title="Base Line Periods")
laggingSpan2Periods = input(52, minval=1, title="Lagging Span 2 Periods"),
displacement = input(26, minval=1, title="Displacement")
profit = input(100, minval=1, title="Profit")
loss = input(100, minval=1, title="Loss")

donchian(len) => avg(lowest(len), highest(len))

conversionLine = donchian(conversionPeriods)
baseLine = donchian(basePeriods)
leadLine1 = avg(conversionLine, baseLine)
leadLine2 = donchian(laggingSpan2Periods)

plot(conversionLine, color=#0496ff, title="Conversion Line")
plot(baseLine, color=#991515, title="Base Line")
plot(close, offset = -displacement + 1, color=#459915, title="Lagging Span")

p1 = plot(leadLine1, offset = displacement - 1, color=color.green,
 title="Lead 1")
p2 = plot(leadLine2, offset = displacement - 1, color=color.red, 
 title="Lead 2")
fill(p1, p2, color = leadLine1 > leadLine2 ? color.green : color.red)

entry()=> crossover (conversionLine, baseLine) and close>baseLine and close>conversionLine


strategy.entry (id="Long entry", long=true, when=entry())
strategy.exit (id="Long exit", profit=200, loss=200)
```

Conditions in visual:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6blon.png)

Comment: `offset` shifts the lines on the chart but in the script there is nothing shifts. You can add `[displacement - 1]` to leadLine1(2) when using them for check the entry condition.

Answer (score 1):

The reason condition number 4 which is **baseline>leadline1 and baseline>leadline2** is not working is because

1. Leadline1 and LeadLine2 both is plotted 26 periods in the future

If you will look at the clouds formed by lead1 and lead2 you must find there are two types of cloud , cloud which is plotted in the future and cloud which is plotted in the same timeframe as baseLine and conversionLine

you have to modify your code in such a way that you are satisfying following two conditions

1. Both base and conversion line is above the cloud(cloud that is in the same timeframe as base and conversion line)

   a = conversionLine > leadLine1[26]

   b = conversionLine > leadLine2[26]

   c = baseLine > leadLine1[26]

   d = baseLine > leadLine2[26]

   e = leadLine1[26] > leadLine2[26]
2. Cloud 26 period in the future is greenish

   f = leadLine1 > leadLine2